# Paste Registry Locations?

Tags: windows-registry, regedit

I find myself editing Windows 7 Registry data on a very regular basis, so much that I've decided to bind Ctrl+R to the Regedit window. However, it'd be very neat for me to be able to paste registry locations — such as 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations' — just like I can copy and paste links in Google Chrome and directories in Windows Explorer. This would save me a lot of time when the registry file itself is not provided on the website that shows me how to do something.

I know these things don't work like Chrome links and directories, but surely this isn't impossible?

Answer (score 2):

To copy paths *from* Regedit, right-click the key (folder) and select "Copy Key Location".

To copy paths *to* Regedit… update to Windows 10, which (only in Insider builds for now) has an actual editable address bar at the top.

There also long have been various third-party registry editors with such features and more.

Alternatively, use the command-line tools:

```
reg add "<paste path here>" /v SomeValue /t REG_DWORD /d 0x1234
```